# convert custom string to json

Tags: javascript, json

How to convert a string to JSON,

**This string to**

```
x:100%,y:20%,radius:50%
```

**Json**

```
{"x":"100%","y":"20%","radius":"50%"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that.

```
var s = "x:100%,y:20%,radius:50%";
var json = JSON.stringify(
    s.split(',').reduce(function(m,v) {
       var t = v.split(':');
       m[t[0]] = t[1];
       return m;
    }, {})
);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ecules/1/edit)

If you want to be compatible with IE8, add [a shim for reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good idea, but you can do this:

```
var j = 'x:100%,y:20%,radius:50%'
j = '{"' + j.replace(/:/g,'":"').replace(/,/g,'","') + '"}'
console.log(j)

{"x":"100%","y":"20%","radius":"50%"}
```

Then you can parse produced string using JSON

```
JSON.parse(j)

Object {x: "100%", y: "20%", radius: "50%"}
```

Comment: @user007 because you should always let the available library do the encoding for you, apart if you perfectly know the JSON format and the values you provide. Quotes may need to be escaped, for example.

Comment: @user007, because this replaces comma and colon, if your values contains those chars. may be something goes wrong

Comment: @dystroy, using JSON object is only for explain and test. it's not cross browser

Comment: Yes, JSON object is not cross browser, in older internet explorers it lacks.

Comment: By older, you mean IE7. Even IE8 has it.